# Is the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{7}})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ a Galois extension?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{7}}) $. Is the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{7}})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ a Galois extension?

Let $x = \sqrt{5 + \sqrt{7}} \implies x^2 = 5 + \sqrt{7} \implies (x^2-5)^2 = 7 \implies x^4 - 10x^2 +18 = 0$
Let $f(x) = x^4 - 10x^2 +18 $.  $f$ is Eisenstein at 2, so $f$ is irreducible and monic.  The minimal polynomial for $\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{7}}$ is then $f$.

$(x-\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{7}})(x+\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{7}})(x-\sqrt{5 - \sqrt{7}})(x+\sqrt{5 - \sqrt{7}}) = f(x)$.

So $K$ is Galois if and only if all the roots of $f$ are in $K$.

$\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{7}} \in K \implies (\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{7}})^{-1} \in K \implies  \frac{\sqrt{5 - \sqrt{7}}}{\sqrt{18}} \in K  \implies \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \sqrt{5 - \sqrt{7}} \in K$

So,  $\sqrt{5 - \sqrt{7}} \in K \iff \sqrt{2} \in K$

I can't prove either.  So maybe it's not Galois???

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  $K$ is Galois over $F=\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{7}]$.  Suppose $\sqrt{5-\sqrt{7}}$ belonged to $K$.  What would the action of $\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)$ on $\sqrt{5+\sqrt{7}}\cdot\sqrt{5-\sqrt{7}}$ be?

Comment: Cute. I'm not sure I have seen this argument before :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Thank you.  Strangely enough I came up with the idea yesterday for a different prove the galois group is $D_4$ question, and then was able to use it twice in one day!

Comment: No effect because automorphisms permute the roots and it would just switch the roots around resulting in the same number.  Okay, I think I got it.  Gal(K/F) would be the trivial group, which we know it is not.

Comment: @csasba  Correct $\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)$ would act trivially on $\sqrt{5+\sqrt{7}}\cdot\sqrt{5-\sqrt{7}}$, but the implication of that is it must belong to $F$, so $\sqrt{5+\sqrt{7}}\cdot\sqrt{5-\sqrt{7}}=3\sqrt{2}$ belongs to $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{7}]$ which is false.