# Is $\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}},\sqrt{2})$?

Tags: field-theory, roots, extension-field, radicals, splitting-field

Is $\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}},\sqrt{2})$?

I'm told that $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt{2})$ is a Galois extension, and so the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ must split in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt{2})$.

The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $x^4-10x^2+5$, whose four roots in $\mathbb{C}$ are:

$\pm \sqrt{5 \pm 2\sqrt{5}}$

And I'm trying to explicitly show that these roots are all contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}},\sqrt{2})$... I'm pretty sure that they are not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}})$ but I don't know how to make $\sqrt{2}$ useful.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716836/is-the-field-extension-mathbbq-sqrt5-sqrt7-over-mathbbq-a-gal?rq=1) is helpful.

Comment: How does the OP conclude that $(\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{7}})^{-1} \in K \implies  \frac{\sqrt{5 - \sqrt{7}}}{\sqrt{18}}$ in that post?

Comment: All the roots lie in $K=\mathbb {Q} (\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}})$. There is no need of $\sqrt{2}$. You should observe that $\sqrt{5}\in K$ and $\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}=\sqrt{5}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $k=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5})$

Let $\mu, \nu \in k$ and we ask when is
$\sqrt{\mu}\in k(\sqrt{\nu})$ if this happens,
$$\sqrt{\mu}=a+b\sqrt{\nu}$$ where $a, b\in k$ and so
$$\mu=a^2+b^2\nu+2ab\sqrt{\nu}$$ and assuming $\sqrt{\mu}, \sqrt{\nu}\not\in k$ we have $a=0$ and
thus
$$\mu=b^2\nu$$

So we ask is $\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}\in k(\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}})$

This is the same as

$$5-2\sqrt{5}=b^2(5+2\sqrt{5})$$
so $$b^2=\frac{5-2\sqrt{5}}{5+2\sqrt{5}}=9-4\sqrt{5}$$

Thus the problem is reduced to whether $9-4\sqrt{5}$ is a perfect square in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5})$, which in turn can be reduced to
$$9-4\sqrt{5}=(n+m\sqrt{5})^2$$ and this has the solution
$$9-4\sqrt{5}=(2-\sqrt{5})^2$$

So

$$5-2\sqrt{5}=(2-\sqrt{5})^2(5+2\sqrt{5})$$
and
$$\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}=(2-\sqrt{5})\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}$$
And thus in the unlikely event that I have made no mistake the answer is yes, $\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}\in k(\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}})$.

Comment: Nicely done! +1.